# Showing only one textview in "popup" window

Tags: android, textview

App takes user input on first screen and when hit submit, only displays "credit limit" and formats for those `TextView` I specify, but not the amounts.  I've taken out some variables for this but it compiles and runs perfectly, just does not show calculations.

Tried making certain variable global and came to conclusion it has to be a matter of something not coming over?  `TextViews` take formatting, which proves to me that the output code is okay, maybe something in data being shared?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intRateInput    = findViewById(R.id.intRateInput);
    limitInput      = findViewById(R.id.limitInput);
    balanceInput    = findViewById(R.id.balanceInput);


    Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent passData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Popup.class);


        dLimit = valueOf(limitInput.getText().toString());                                      //TAKE USER INPUT FROM MAIN SCREEN
        passData.putExtra("limitInput", dLimit);                                            //PASS INPUT TO POP-UP


            dBalance    =   valueOf(balanceInput.getText().toString());                             //TAKE USER INPUT FROM MAIN SCREEN
            passData.putExtra("balanceInput", dBalance);                                       //PASS INPUT TO POP-UP


            dIntRate    =   valueOf(intRateInput.getText().toString());                             //TAKE USER INPUT FROM MAIN SCREEN
            passData.putExtra("intRateInput", dIntRate);                                        //PASS INPUT TO POP-UP
            startActivity(passData);}
```

This is the second code for the `PopupWindow` displaying user input.  It receives information passed on through `Intent` and I am hoping that I did it correctly.  The application compiles and runs correctly but only shows the "original balance" but not the rest of the `TextViews`.

Could someone look at the code to help me find out where I am not working out correctly?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);


    Intent passData = getIntent();
    dCurrentLimit = passData.getDoubleExtra("limitInput", dLimit);
    dCurrentBal = passData.getDoubleExtra("balance", dBalance);
    dCurrentIntRate = passData.getDoubleExtra("intRateInput", dIntRate);

    Calculate();

}

public void Calculate(){

    int     iDays   =   30;


    TextView minMonPay = findViewById(R.id.minMonPay);
    TextView textClose = findViewById(R.id.textclose);
    TextView cashFlowRec = findViewById(R.id.cashFlowRec);
    TextView origMonPayCal = findViewById(R.id.origMonPayCal);
    TextView origBalIn = findViewById(R.id.origBalIn);

    DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat ("$#,###.00");
    currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);

    //double  monthly     =   (dBalance * dActRate) / iMonth;
    //double  result      =   (dBalance * dActRate) / iMonth / iDays;

    dMinDailyCharge     =   dCurrentBal * dInterest / iMonth;

    dInterest           =   dCurrentIntRate / dPercent;
    dOrigMonCharge      =   dCurrentBal * dInterest / iMonth;


    minMonPay.setText(currency.format(dMinMonthlyCharge));
    origMonPayCal.setText(currency.format(dBalance));                                               //SHOW ORIGINAL MONTHLY INTEREST CHARGE
    origBalIn.setText(currency.format(dCurrentLimit));                                              //SHOW ORIGINAL BALANCE
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i see the code, youre passing wrong key to get the dbalance amount. in the first code snippet you passed `passData.putExtra("balanceInput", dBalance);` and youre collecting the value of key that doesnot exist `dCurrentBal = passData.getDoubleExtra("balance", dBalance);` pay attention to the key youre using.

and its a good practice to initialize all widgets you used while creating the activity.  move all `findViewById` to onCreate method and try again. let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you Madhu s.  I've spent so much time looking through the code that I became complacent in the code itself.  Unfortunately, it still does not work.  Once I moved the `findViewById` to onCreate method, app compiles, takes information, and stops working altogether.  Before I moved them over to onCreate, I tried testing the app and it still did not display the information.

Comment: did you try changing Key you're collecting in the next activity?

Comment: I changed key to match 'dBalance'

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);

        TextView minMonPay = findViewById(R.id.minMonPay);
        TextView textClose = findViewById(R.id.textclose);
        TextView cashFlowRec = findViewById(R.id.cashFlowRec);
        TextView origMonPayCal = findViewById(R.id.origMonPayCal);
        TextView origBalIn = findViewById(R.id.origBalIn);

Comment: Intent passData = getIntent();
        dCurrentLimit = passData.getDoubleExtra("limitInput", dLimit);
        dCurrentBal = passData.getDoubleExtra("balanceInput", dBalance);
        dCurrentIntRate = passData.getDoubleExtra("intRateInput", dIntRate);

        Calculate();
    }

Comment: @sonnykekipi  try replacing this code in oncreate method by `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) { dCurrentLimit = passData.getDoubleExtra("limitInput", dLimit);
    dCurrentBal = passData.getDoubleExtra("balance", dBalance);
    dCurrentIntRate = passData.getDoubleExtra("intRateInput", dIntRate);}` let me know if it works.

Comment: I did as you said and the program fails.  I played around with it and it seems that there is still a "null" value being thrown, as if it is not recognizing the user input.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.krstrat.financialslider.Popup.Calculate(Popup.java:92)
        at com.krstrat.financialslider.Popup.onCreate(Popup.java:62)

Comment: It seems that none of the user input is being taken now because when I comment out one line of code for the calculation, it points to the next line of code being 'null' as well.